# Magento - Overwrite core 'Review' module to add custom 'Email' field

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I need to create a custom module which over writes the existing 'Review' Module to add an extra field 'Email Id'

I believe I need to over write core Model files '**app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Resource/Review.php**' ,'**app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Resource/Review/Product/Collection.php**' and Block file '**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php**'

Also I don't know what setup script and with what version should I include to upgrade the existing 'review_detail' table with this extra field.

This is what I have done so far code wise and it doesn't work. For now I have manually added 'email' field in review_detail table and added email input field in base/default/template/review/form.phtml

```
CM
 Review
   Block
     Review
       Edit
        Form.php
   etc
     config.xml
   Helper
     Data.php
   Model
     Resource
       Review.php
       Review
          Product
             Collection.php
```

This is my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <CM_Review>
     <version>0.0.1</version>
    </CM_Review>
 </modules>
 <frontend>
  <routers>
    <review>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>CM_Review</module>
            <frontName>Review</frontName>
        </args>
     </review>
   </routers>
 </frontend>    
 <global>
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
        <review_edit_form>CM_Review_Block_Review_Edit_Form</review_edit_form>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
<helpers>
    <review>
       <rewrite>
            <class>CM_Review_Helper</class>
       </rewrite>
    </review>
     </helpers>  
      <models>
       <review>
         <rewrite>
           <resource_review>CM_Review_Model_Resource_Review</resource_review>
            <resource_review_product_collection>
                CM_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Product_Collection
              </resource_review_product_collection>
         </rewrite>
      </review>
     </models>
    </global>
   </config>
```

I have copy pasted the content of original Block and Model files with addition of 'email' field. But still can't get to save any data. However directly editing the original files does the trick but not through my custom module.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing out on? Any pointers for help will do. Thanks.

---

I am getting no error but also the field is neither getting saved to the database nor its getting added through install script code. Hence I commented the resources section from my code and added the field manually. This is my code,

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
  <CM_Reviewmail>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
  </CM_Reviewmail>
</modules>

<frontend>
  <routers>
    <reviewmail>
       <use>standard</use>
       <args>
          <module>CM_Reviewmail</module>
          <frontName>cmreviewmail</frontName>
       </args>
    </reviewmail>
  </routers>
</frontend>     
<global>

 <blocks>
   <adminhtml>
      <rewrite>
        <review_edit_form>CM_Reviewmail_Block_Review_Edit_Form</review_edit_form>
      </rewrite>
  </adminhtml>
</blocks>

<helpers>
  <reviewmail>
     <class>CM_Reviewmail_Helper</class>
   </reviewmail>
</helpers> 

<models>
  <reviewmail>
     <rewrite>
        <resource_review>CM_Reviewmail_Model_Resource_Review</resource_review>
     </rewrite>
  </reviewmail>
</models>

<!-- <resources>
    <reviewmail_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>CM_Reviewmail</module>
            <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </reviewmail_setup>
    <reviewmail_setup_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </reviewmail_setup_write>
    <reviewmail_setup_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </reviewmail_setup_read>
</resources>-->

</global>
</config>
```

This is my Reviewmail/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php code

```
 <?php
class CM_Reviewmail_Block_Review_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form
{
 protected function _prepareForm()
 {
    $review = Mage::registry('review_data');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($review->getEntityPkValue());
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($review->getCustomerId());
    $statuses = Mage::getModel('review/review')
        ->getStatusCollection()
        ->load()
        ->toOptionArray();

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'        => 'edit_form',
        'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'), 'ret' => Mage::registry('ret'))),
        'method'    => 'post'
    ));

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('review_details', array('legend' => Mage::helper('review')->__('Review Details'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));

    $fieldset->addField('product_name', 'note', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Product'),
        'text'      => '<a href="' . $this->getUrl('*/catalog_product/edit', array('id' => $product->getId())) . '" onclick="this.target=\'blank\'">' . $product->getName() . '</a>'
    ));

    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $customerText = Mage::helper('review')->__('<a href="%1$s" onclick="this.target=\'blank\'">%2$s %3$s</a> <a href="mailto:%4$s">(%4$s)</a>',
            $this->getUrl('*/customer/edit', array('id' => $customer->getId(), 'active_tab'=>'review')),
            $this->htmlEscape($customer->getFirstname()),
            $this->htmlEscape($customer->getLastname()),
            $this->htmlEscape($customer->getEmail()));
    } else {
        if (is_null($review->getCustomerId())) {
            $customerText = Mage::helper('review')->__('Guest');
        } elseif ($review->getCustomerId() == 0) {
            $customerText = Mage::helper('review')->__('Administrator');
        }
    }

    $fieldset->addField('customer', 'note', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Posted By'),
        'text'      => $customerText,
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('summary_rating', 'note', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Summary Rating'),
        'text'      => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/review_rating_summary')->toHtml(),
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('detailed_rating', 'note', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Detailed Rating'),
        'required'  => true,
        'text'      => '<div id="rating_detail">' . $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/review_rating_detailed')->toHtml() . '</div>',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('status_id', 'select', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Status'),
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'status_id',
        'values'    => Mage::helper('review')->translateArray($statuses),
    ));

    /**
     * Check is single store mode
     */
    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $fieldset->addField('select_stores', 'multiselect', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Visible In'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'stores[]',
            'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm()
        ));
        $review->setSelectStores($review->getStores());
    }
    else {
        $fieldset->addField('select_stores', 'hidden', array(
            'name'      => 'stores[]',
            'value'     => Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId()
        ));
        $review->setSelectStores(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId());
    }

    $fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array( //CUSTOM field
    'label' => Mage::helper('review')->__('Email'),
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'email'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('nickname', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Nickname'),
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'nickname'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Summary of Review'),
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'title',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('detail', 'textarea', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('review')->__('Review'),
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'detail',
        'style'     => 'height:24em;',
    ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $form->setValues($review->getData());
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
   }    
 }
```

This is my Reviewmail/Model/Resources/Review.php code

```
   <?php 
   class CM_Reviewmail_Model_Resource_Review extends Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review
   {
protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
    {
     $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
     /**
     * save detail
     */
     $detail = array(
        'title'     => $object->getTitle(),
        'detail'    => $object->getDetail(),
        'nickname'  => $object->getNickname(),
        'email'     => $object->getEmail(),
    );
    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->_reviewDetailTable, 'detail_id')
        ->where('review_id = :review_id');
    $detailId = $adapter->fetchOne($select, array(':review_id' => $object->getId()));

    if ($detailId) {
        $condition = array("detail_id = ?" => $detailId);
        $adapter->update($this->_reviewDetailTable, $detail, $condition);
    } else {
        $detail['store_id']   = $object->getStoreId();
        $detail['customer_id']= $object->getCustomerId();
        $detail['review_id']  = $object->getId();
        $adapter->insert($this->_reviewDetailTable, $detail);
    }


    /**
     * save stores
     */
    $stores = $object->getStores();
    if (!empty($stores)) {
        $condition = array('review_id = ?' => $object->getId());
        $adapter->delete($this->_reviewStoreTable, $condition);

        $insertedStoreIds = array();
        foreach ($stores as $storeId) {
            if (in_array($storeId, $insertedStoreIds)) {
                continue;
            }

            $insertedStoreIds[] = $storeId;
            $storeInsert = array(
                'store_id' => $storeId,
                'review_id'=> $object->getId()
            );
            $adapter->insert($this->_reviewStoreTable, $storeInsert);
        }
    }

    // reaggregate ratings, that depend on this review
    $this->_aggregateRatings(
        $this->_loadVotedRatingIds($object->getId()),
        $object->getEntityPkValue()
    );

    return $this;
  } 
}
```

There is a Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
 class CM_Reviewmail_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {}
```

This is Model/Resource/Mysql4/Setup.php

```
<?php
class CM_Reviewmail_Model_Resource_Mysl4_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {}
```

Can any one point out what have i done wrong? or what more needs to be done?

Please any help is appreciated. I have been banging my head against the wall and need to sort this problem asap. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I wasn't declaring my resource files correctly in my config.xml. This is how I did it now.

```
<models>
<review_resource>
     <rewrite>
       <review>CM_Reviewmail_Model_Resource_Review</review>
       <collection>CM_Reviewmail_Model_Resource_Review_Collection</collection>
       <product_collection>CM_Reviewmail_Model_Resource_Review_Product_Collection</product_collection>
    </rewrite>
 </review_resource>
</models>
```

And then I created the above mentioned files making sure to extend their original classes and just overwrote the functions that needs to be changed. Eventually I was able to save the fields in the database with registered/guest customer's email id.

However, when I tried fetching these email values using the below query,

```
 Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('email', $emailId)
                ->addFieldToFilter('status_id' , '1')
                ->addFieldToSelect('email')->getData();
```

it dint return me anything. When I executed it in phpMyAdmin I got this query

```
 SELECT `main_table`.`email`, `detail`.`detail_id`, `detail`.`title`, `detail`.`detail`, `detail`.`nickname`, `detail`.`customer_id` FROM `review` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `review_detail` AS `detail` ON main_table.review_id = detail.review_id WHERE (email = 'test@test.com') AND (status_id = '1')
```

which gave an error saying 'Unknown `main_table.email` field in the list'.

Now can anyone please help me point out the problem so as to why its saving the data but not letting me fetch it? Why it's not recognizing my field when its saving data to it? IS my query wrong?

PS: however if I replace the 'main_table.email' with just 'email' in the above query in phpMyAdmin and execute it, it does return me the proper value. So is there a way to write the query in the code by scrapping of the 'main_table' part?

Comment: Is there a way to only select 'email' field instead of 'main_table.email'? I believe this can be done through joins but I am not fully sure as to how to prepare a JOIN for my query?

Comment: Hey guys, I had asked this question separately on the forum too but kinda ended up creating a raw sql query for the time being. But as soon as I find a proper fix for this, I will change it back to the magento way. This is the link to it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966026/select-a-field-without-e-or-main-table-magento/8971788#8971788 . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your method for rewriting the class looks mostly right, but remember that you are rewriting `adminhtml/review_edit_form` to point to CM_Review_Block_Review_Edit_Form, so in `app/code/local/CM/Review/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php` you need to be declaring the class as such:

```
<?php
    class CM_Review_Block_Review_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form
    {
```

And then only override the functions that you need to.

Don't know if you are doing that already. The same process applies for any models that you rewrite. You shouldn't really need to rewrite the collection for this either, but that's up to you depending on what you need to do with it.

As for the install stuff:

in `app/code/local/CM/Review/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    ...
    <resources>
        <review_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>CM_Review</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </review_setup>
    </resources>
    ...
</config>
```

In `app/code/local/CM/Review/sql/review_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php`

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $installer->run("ALTER TABLE review_detail ADD COLUMN email_id INT NULL");
    $installer->endSetup();
```

If this doesn't take the first time (it should, unless you've tried something similar already), go into the database, and remove the "`review_setup`" row from the table "`core_resource`". Then try again. After adding columns, always remember to flush the magento cache in `System > Cache Management`

Don't forget that you also need to create a file called `CM_Review.xml` in `app/etc/modules`. It should look like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CM_Review>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </CM_Review>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have pretty much done the same thing. Except that I dont understand why you have declared **<class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>. I need review and not Sales. And when I only over ride the functions I want, the Review form doesn't display at all.

Comment: Also in my config.xml code above, hopefully my <models></models>part is correct ? Because I suspect that might be the part where I am going wrong. should it be <resource_review> or <review_resource>?

Comment: Changed my config.xml to include the <resources> part for install stuff that you have mentioned. I also have removed the Collection rewrite part in <models>. Still it gives me Magento error page not able to find my review form page whenever I try to open the form. Surely I am going wrong with <models> rewrite part and <resources> part.

Comment: I also get this error whenever I uncomment my <resources>section and try to add the new field through my install script, a:5:{i:0;s:66:"/home/atsdev/public_html/app/code///sql/reviewmail_setup not found";i:1;s:814:"#0

Comment: Any pointers anyone? Still stuck on the same thing. Have tried quite a couple things but to no success. Starting to wonder, if there is any other way to do it without adding extra field to table or overriding Model files.

Comment: Surely there is only some thing that I am writing or declaring wrong wrt Model files because if I directly edit the original Model/Resource/Review.php it saves itself but If i include the same change in my module then it doesn't save it?

Answer (score 0):

here is mistake

```
<product_collection>CM_Reviewmail_Model_Resource_Review_Product_Collection</product_collection>
```

should be

```
<review_product_collection>CM_Reviewmail_Model_Resource_Review_Product_Collection</review_product_collection>
```