# Select a field without `e.` or `main_table` - Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, select

This question follows from one of my other questions on this forum. I have created a custom module and have overridden 'Review' model's core files. It allows me to save data to my custom field 'email' fine. But when I try to retrieve the values of this field, it doesn't recognize my field at all.

This is my query,

```
Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('status_id' , '1')
->addFieldToFilter('email', $emailId)
->addFieldToSelect('email');
```

And this is what I get when I echo it,

```
 SELECT `main_table`.`email` AS `review_detail`, `detail`.`detail_id`, `detail`.`title`, `detail`.`detail`, `detail`.`nickname`, `detail`.`customer_id` FROM `review` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `review_detail` AS `detail` ON main_table.review_id = detail.review_id WHERE (status_id = '1') AND (email = 'test@test.com')
```

Its obviously trying to select email from `main_table` which is `review` table instead of `review_detail` table. Is there a way to select `email` field without `main_table` prefix or just change the query such that it selects `email` from `review_detail` table?

Please help me out. I have come across posts related to `joins` but not sure if that is one of the options in my case or not. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the quick way to get it running for now is that I have directly passed a SQL query in the code. I know that's not the right way to do it but any thing I tried was certainly not helping. This is my code:

```
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
  $query = "SELECT a.review_id, b.email FROM  review AS a INNER JOIN review_detail AS b WHERE a.review_id = b.review_id AND a.status_id = 1 AND b.email = '" . $emailId. "'";  
  $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

I know this is not the right way to write a magento code but to get it working quickly, I had no other option. I would keep looking for a proper solution and would amend it once I get it. If anyone else could think of writing this same thing but the Magento way please let me know.

Thanks for your help so far every one.

Answer (score 1):

I know the Problem is old, but I just had the same, so for all you people in the future, this is how you do it the easiest way, without using plain sql:

```
Mage::getModel('review/review')
->getCollection()
->addExpressionFieldToSelect('email','detail.email');
```

It becomes: `detail.email AS email`

Answer (score 0):

As you have not specified a table alias for the `email` field in the `addFieldToSelect` method, the system is defaulting it to `main_table.email`

If you have a look at the query, it's joining onto the `review_detail` with a table alias of `detail`.

```
INNER JOIN `review_detail` AS `detail`
```

You should be able to select (and filter) on the `email` from the `review_detail` table by specifying `` `detail`.email `` instead of just `email`.

Comment: I did try that and its still not happening. How do you write the using `detail.email` in the above code? Maybe I am syntactically writing it wrong?

Comment: I used the ` (backquote). What do you get when you echo using `detail.email`

Comment: When I echo `detail`.'email' I get `SELECT `main_table.`detailemail` ...` ..It just doesn't recognize that `email` field is from review_detail and not review table.

Comment: The way I have done this before is to add a join after I get the collection, but it looks like you are doing this in the overridden code. One other thing you could do is change the name of the email column in the review_detail table...bit dodgy, but it would work

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not using table alias name thats why, you are getting email from main table.
You will use 'detail' .email = 'test@test.com'

Comment: What should I write in order to use `detail` as the table alias name while selecting my email field in `addFieldToSelect` line?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status_id' , '1')
    ->addFilter('my_cool_filter',
        $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('detail.email=?', $emailId),
        'string'
    );
```

Comment: I tried to echo this query by appending a getSelect() to it but it dint return anything. Seems like the query isn't getting formed at all?

Comment: Have no idea. Is `$this->getConnection()` exists and is object of right class in that place where you copy-pasted this code?

Comment: Well i tried echoing `$this->getConnection()` but it dint print out anything as well. I think I need to do `$resource->getConnection()` maybe where `$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');` ?

Comment: Then instead of `$this->getConnection()` use `Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()->getConnection()`